# maven ear plugin not copying all jar files from WEB-INF/lib of one of the war

Tags: java, maven, build, war, ear

Our product has more four web modules; the maven script of the individual module builds the war file of respective web-modules by bringing all the dependencies as mentioned in pom.xml. We are also doing an overlay of a third-party module that copies additional jar files into WEB-INF/lib folder.

In the end, To simplify the distribution we are trying to create a single enterprise archive (ear) file which includes all war files along with its dependencies.

The maven-ear plugin, we are using copies only the jar files mentioned in pom.xml of sub-modules, not the ones copied by the result of the overlay.

Any help on this much appreciated.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>web</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>singleear</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <properties>
        <mod.version>7.12.0.Final</mod.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
            <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
            <artifactId>module3</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
            <artifactId>module4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.3rdparty.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>other</artifactId>
            <version>x.x.x.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencies used by project -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
                            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>/module1.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/module1</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
                            <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>/module2.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/module2</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
                            <artifactId>module3</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>/module3.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/module3</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>org.dept.prod</groupId>
                            <artifactId>module4</artifactId>
                            <bundleFileName>/module4.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/module4</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please show the full pom files which you are using ....

Comment: Attached script to build ear

Comment: Overlays are intended to share resources over different war files but not jar files which are dependencies...furthermore are the given war files in the example pom file the overlayed artifacts which are produced ? One more thing. Are those modules all within a single multi module build?

Comment: Yes, the war files in the example pom file are the modules. One of the modules has an overlay of a 3rd party product

Answer (score 0):

```
<skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
```

this property make to not copy libs into war module